# Compute a Monte Carlo estimate. Which of the variances (of $\hat{\theta}$ and $\hat{\theta}^{*}$) is smaller, and why?

Tags: statistical-significance, variance, monte-carlo, estimators, computational-statistics

Compute a Monte Carlo estimate $\hat{\theta}$ of $$ \theta = \int_{0}^{0.5} e^{-x} dx $$ by sampling from Uniform$(0, 0.5)$, and estimate the variance of $\hat{\theta}$. Find another Monte Carlo estimator $\theta^{*}$ by sampling from the exponential distribution. Which of the variances (of $\hat{\theta}$ and $\hat{\theta}^{*}$) is smaller, and why?

Hello,

For this I get that my $\hat{\theta} \approx 0.3940$ and $\hat{\theta}^{*} \approx 0.3919$ with variances

Var$\left( \hat{\theta} \right) = 3.17370512597548e-07
 < 2.38251575157516e-05 =$Var$\left( \hat{\theta}^* \right)$.

However, I am having problems understanding why is smaller. Can someone explain?

Comment: The variances can be computed exactly for both estimates. "Why?" is a vague question as I could reply "because the maths show it is the case". But the choice based on the exponential distribution is poor because the function to be integrated is zero with a large probability, which induces a waste of simulation power.

Comment: Please add `self-study`to the tags.